# Python: Get value from one set columns based on minimum value from another set of columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So I have a pandas dataframe with 8 columns:

```
> 'percent_perfect_1-5_diff', 'percent_perfect_6-10_diff',
> 'percent_perfect_11-20_diff','percent_perfect_21-50_diff',
> 'median_sale_price_1-5', 'median_sale_price_6-10',
> 'median_sale_price_11-20', 'median_sale_price_21-50'.
```

The 'percent_perfect' columns are one group that is further subdivided into numbered groups.The corresponding prices for each group are in the 'median_sale_price'.

I want to add a 9th column called "group_price". The logic is - whichever "percent_perfect" column has the least absolute value, I want its corresponding median_sale_price value. So if "percent_perfect_1-5_diff' has the minimum absolute value amongst all 4 columns, I want the value in "median_sale_price_1-5" and so on.

I have tried doing this:

```
df.filter(like='percent_perfect_').abs().idxmin(axis=1)
```

This gives me the percent_perfect columns id but how do I proceed to get the median_sale_price?

Comment: split the output of that, get the suffixes, e.g. `1_5, 21_50,...`, prepend by `median_sale_price_`, then extract with [lookup](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.3.2/user_guide/indexing.html#indexing-lookup).

Comment: this data is quite messy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the trouble you're having is because you haven't tidied your data. Once you tidy it, it's a very easy operation to perform:

```
import pandas as pd
import random

random.seed(0)

# generate random example data, since you didn't provide a sample input
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'percent_perfect_1-5_diff': [random.uniform(-1, 1) for _ in range(10)],
    'percent_perfect_6-10_diff': [random.uniform(-1, 1) for _ in range(10)],
    'percent_perfect_11-20_diff': [random.uniform(-1, 1) for _ in range(10)],
    'percent_perfect_21-50_diff': [random.uniform(-1, 1) for _ in range(10)],
    'median_sale_price_1-5': [random.randint(100000, 500000) for _ in range(10)],
    'median_sale_price_6-10': [random.randint(100000, 500000) for _ in range(10)],
    'median_sale_price_11-20': [random.randint(100000, 500000) for _ in range(10)],
    'median_sale_price_21-50': [random.randint(100000, 500000) for _ in range(10)],
})


# the data is a bit of a mess (you shouldn't store data in column names ***ever***
# we tidy the data, so the columns are original row #, range, percent_perfect, and median_sale_price
df = (df.stack()
   .reset_index()
   .assign(range = lambda x: x['level_1'].str.extract(r'(\d+-\d+)'), 
           level_1 = lambda x: x['level_1'].str.extract(r'(.*)(?=_\d+)'))
   .pivot(index=['level_0', 'range'], columns='level_1', values=0)
   .reset_index())

# find the median sale price for the row with the lowest absolute percent_perfect, grouped by original row #
(df.groupby('level_0')['percent_perfect'].apply(lambda x: x.abs().idxmin())
.apply(lambda x: df.loc[x, 'median_sale_price']))
```

Output:

```
level_0
0    206536.0
1    216236.0
2    358776.0
3    389022.0
4    227879.0
5    482876.0
6    165436.0
7    412626.0
8    133021.0
9    200174.0
```

Comment: for more information on tidy data, take a look at this: https://www.jeannicholashould.com/tidy-data-in-python.html